# Какие способы оптимизации Woocommerce принесли результаты?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Какие способы оптимизации Woocommerce принесли результаты? Поделитесь пожалуйста техниками, статьями, которые будут полезны всем кто заглянет в этот вопрос.

Конкретно сейчас внедряю этот прием - [Произвольная таблица с индексами](https://wordpress.tv/2017/12/25/konstantin-kovshenin-custom-database-tables/). А какие приёмы использовали Вы?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Отключаю](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/disable-woocommerce-assets/) стили и скрипты на тех страницах, где их быть не должно.
2. [Кэширую](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pomodoro-cache/) переводы при помощи Pomodoro
3. [Отключаю](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/wordpress-optimization-with-disable-translation-for-rest-api/) переводы для запросов REST.
4. [Исправляю](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/removing-post-not-in/) запросы с post__not_in, заменяя его на цыкл.

Но прежде чем всё это затевать - соберите профиль вашего сайта при помощи xDebug, xhprof. Тогда будет понятно, в какую сторону копать.